# how draw curves lines

Tags: java, android, draw

Please, someone could help me draw this line in red color between point A(720,1140) the middle oof circle and point B (375,490)

[image]

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int x = metrics.widthPixels;
    int y = metrics.heightPixels;
    Paint paint1 = new Paint () ;
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(10);
    int margin = 100;
    int margin1 = 300;
    int top = 0 + margin;
    int bottom = canvas.getHeight() - margin;
    int left = 0 + margin1;
    int right = canvas.getWidth() - margin1;
    int centerX = x / 2;
    int centerY = y / 2;
    canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, 50, paint1);
    canvas.drawLine(centerX, top, centerX, bottom,paint1);
    canvas.drawLine(left, centerY, right, centerY,paint1);
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You should post the code that you tried to accomplish this

Comment: @Lexi I know just draw straight lines, I tried with quadto cubicto , I have not succeeded

Comment: Rather than explain, you need to post your code. This question is too broad without it

Comment: @Lexi Here I posted my part of the code that works

Comment: @azurefrog Just a little help, what point I need to be able to draw this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

- Found the point in between the 2 given points
- Calculated the angle 90 degrees between the 2 points
- Calculated the point X pixels from the middle point using the calculated degree from before.
- Used "path.cubicTo" with these 3 points (Takes both negative and positive
  values to determine which way the line should curve).

Here is my code!

```
public PaintApplication drawCurve(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int curveRadius, int padding, int color, int lineWidth) {

        Paint paint  = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color));

        final Path path = new Path();
        int midX            = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
        int midY            = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
        float xDiff         = midX - x1;
        float yDiff         = midY - y1;
        double angle        = (Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * (180 / Math.PI)) - 90;
        double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);
        float pointX        = (float) (midX + curveRadius * Math.cos(angleRadians));
        float pointY        = (float) (midY + curveRadius * Math.sin(angleRadians));

        path.moveTo(x1, y1);
        path.cubicTo(x1,y1,pointX, pointY, x2, y2);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        return this;
    }
```

I created a Paint application based on this coding idea.

For screenshot refer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfghJ.png)

Hope this helps !!