# coordinate X Y draw Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, draw

I programmed a drawing application, I want to retrieve all the X Y of my drawing. That is to say each time I touch the screen, the coordinates x and y I put them in a two dimensional table ,

I made a toast to find out when the coordinates change, and I found that they change in the movetouch method, so I declare a table in the method and I still make a toast to see the 10 line Of my array, the toast changed co-ordination so I understood that in fact values ​​are crushed whenever the x and y change, or I am planting

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                   startTouch(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    upTouch();
                    invalidate();
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    moveTouche(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Method moveTouch

```
  public void moveTouche (float x,float y ) {
    if ((canDraw)&& drawing) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if(dx >= Tolerance || dy >= Tolerance){
        path.quadTo(mX,mY,(x+mX)/2,(y+mY)/2);
        mX = x ;
        mY = y;
        double[][]  point = new double [99][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {

            point[i][0]=x;
            point[i][1]=y;


        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"y = "+point[10][1]+" ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }}
}
```

[image]

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @AndyTurner it's give me just one point

Comment: you want something to draw on the screen where the user touches ?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal No, I could do that, I want the coordinates of my drawing, suddenly all points by or my finger is past

Comment: So are you creating a table of all those coordinates?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Yes I created a table

Comment: are you using this same code as i suggested you on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304280/how-draw-curves-lines

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal This one I used to draw a curved line, but after that the user will draw on top and I want to compare the two drawing, so via coordinates x y, to trigger the button

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I THINK THAT I MUST DECLARE MY TABLE IN MOTION ACTION BUT THE PROBLEM IS THAT IT FILLS THE TABLE WITH A SINGLE POINT THEN IT WRITES IT TO COMPLETE ALL THE TABLE WITH THE SECOND POINT

Comment: can you share a screenshot so that i can understand you problem more clearly? like what kind of table? where it is generated in same activity or fragment?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I edited my question to make it clearer, Simpler I want that every time I touch the screen, a two-dimensional array fills with the x and y coordinates

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal So !? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read as many points as you want from any path. Example how to read coordinates from the middle of path:

```
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(myPath, false);
//coordinates will be here
float aCoordinates[] = {0f, 0f};

//get coordinates of the middle point
pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.5f, aCoordinates, null);
```

You can pass any distance from the path start to get point coordinates.

Comment: thank you :) Just another question, if the drawing was a straight line that I already draw (black) or the curved lines that you showed me how the drawn, I recover how the coordinates to be compared with the coordinates of the Red drawing, so trigger an animation

Comment: Glad I could stick with you and helped you :) Accept and upvote this answer if my answer helped you .

Comment: Comparing two curves okay let me see what i can do for your next problem :)

Comment: for exemple i have `canvas.drawLine(x/2,y/2,x/2,top,paint1);` and `path1.moveTo(720, 1230);
        path1.cubicTo(720, 1230, pointX2, pointY2, 290, 1950);
        canvas.drawPath(path1, paint);`  I want to retrieve the coordinates of these two lines, how you showed me, and compared the two array

Comment: How can i print the result ?

Comment: give me some time.  I will get back to your problem